# How to get value by id using DomDocument?

Tags: php, domdocument

I am trying to get value of form below using DomDocument but so far still failed

```
<?php
$string ='<form action="profile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="id_user" id="id_user" value="123">
    <input type="hidden" name="logo" id="logo" value="path/to/logo1.png">
    <input type="hidden" name="status" id="status" value="Ok">
    <input type="submit" value="PROFILE">
</form>';
?>
```

How to properly use DomDocument in this case?

I was trying below code

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($string);
$dom->getElementById("id_user");
```

I was expecting to get 123 as returned value

Comment: As Kiko answers, the reference you have is for the DOM object - not its value property. you need to put the output of `$dom->getElementById("id_user")` into a variable and access the value property.

Answer (score 1):

DomDocument is a bit of a fiddle, but if you follow the documentation you can get there. I found this route:

```
$dom->getElementById("id_user")->attributes->getNamedItem("value")->value
```

This returns:

```
123
```

See: https://onlinephp.io/c/c37dc

There might be other ways to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using xpath:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
echo($xpath->query('//form//input[@id="id_user"]/@value')[0]->value);
```